# Are tenure-track applicants background checked?

Tags: united-states, job, faculty-application

What's the standard procedure in tenure-track jobs when it comes to "background checks"?
Do they call my current employer or is it limited to a "criminal background check"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd expect the following:

- Some institutions do a criminal background check, others don't.  This will usually be disclosed in the job ad.  For those that do, they might do the check before making an offer (in which case the application will ask for the necessary identifying information), or they might make you an offer that's contingent on passing the check.
- US faculty jobs will require letters of recommendation, or contact information for references.  The search committee might actually contact them to ask further questions about you.  (Your recommenders might or might not tell you if this happens.)
- They will normally not contact anybody other than your letter writers or references you list in your application.  This is pretty important because people in existing faculty positions often don't want it known within their department that they are on the market; it could have political blowback if they end up not leaving.

Comment: Thank you, Nate. They have already contacted everyone in my reference list, and they all said good things about me. So then, it's probably safe to assume that they will focus on a criminal background check. Also, I remember the dean mentioning that the only thing left for me to do would be a criminal background check. I hope that that's all.

Comment: My institution also verified my degrees during the background check.

Comment: "They will normally not contact anybody other than your letter writers or references you list in your application." However, a lot of potential employers will insist that your line manager in your current job must be among those references.

Comment: @DanielHatton: That's not my experience for academic employers in the US.  There is an unwritten expectation that you will have a reference from *someone* at your current institution, but not necessarily your "line manager" (= department chair?); it can be a trusted colleague instead.  As noted, it's understood that you may not want to tell your department chair you are applying for other jobs.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's a very bad practice for the exactly reason you suggest, but here in the UK it's also an extremely common practice, among employers both inside and outside the university sector.

Comment: @DanielHatton: I see, but this question is tagged [tag:united-states].

Comment: @NateEldredge Didn't spot that, thanks.