# background check before interviews

Tags: united-states, tenure-track

Is it normal to have a background check before having an on-site interview for a tenure-track assistant professor position in US?

Comment: What sort of background check?

Comment: normal ones, criminal, stealing etc

Comment: If the university is paying for a candidate's travel, I can see why they might want to be sure there are no future roadblocks first.

Comment: usually university pays it without a background check

Answer (score 4):

If the institution wants to conduct a criminal background check, I would expect it to occur [around the time an offer is made](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/108448/17254), not before an on-site interview.

Comment: this is what i used to believe. is there a research university in US doing sth different?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not American, and depending on the state and University laws of wherever you are applying, you may be subject to extra background checks. This is the case especially for individuals from China, Iran, Cuba, Russia, Venezuela, Syria, etc....

These background checks can take extra time and are run by a third party contractor. To expedite hiring processes, a lot of places are running these checks in parallel to the interview process. Basically, anyone slated to come on campus gets the background checks started. While this is tedious and costly because it means you pay for 3+ background checks even for hiring one person, it does mean you can move quickly to make an official offer once a candidate is moved forward. Additionally, if the first choice candidate declines, the second choice is already background checked and an immediate offer can be made.

Comment: It might be cheaper then performing an interview for 3 people and finding out that 2 of them didn't pass a background check.... Interviews cost the time of expensive people.

Comment: that makes sense

Comment: I have been on over a dozen hiring committees in the past three years alone... the background check is just a formality to satisfy legalities. Especially for foreign candidates, they have been vetted by USCIS anyways. Similarly, for US Nationals and permanent residents, they have likely undergone a recent background check for their current postdoc (or current faculty position) anyway. Hence why Universities just run this in parallel so they can get it out of the way and get to an offer as soon as possible. Of course if they do find something they won't make an offer... but that's very rare.